# How do I stack two or more figures on top of each other?

Tags: floats, formatting, subfloats

I am trying to get two figures to stack on top of each other. How can I do that? My code looks like this.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}  
    \begin{document}  
    \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=.4]{images/svdDimReduc.png}
            \caption{top: SVD 4x4 matrix}
            \includegraphics[scale=.4]{images/svdDimReduc2.png}
            \caption{bottom: SVD 4x4 matrix calculation}
            \label{fig:svdDimReductions.png}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

But Latex made it to two figures in my result. [image: my result]

What I want is this:
[image: I want it look like this]

Comment: Please always provide a Minimal Working Example. There can be very different ways to answer you, depending on the packages you're using (especially when it comes to figures).

Comment: If you can use the `memoir` documentclass, then commands such as `\subbottom` may be used, with two subfigures stacked by simply inserting `\\` between their `\subbottom` expression. (see page 201 of the `memoir` documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you'd want to use the [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, which defines a `subfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
    \caption{top: SVD 4x4 matrix}
    \label{subfig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-b}
    \caption{bottom: SVD 4x4 matrix calculation}
    \label{subfig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main figure}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: subfigure example]

Comment: cool thanks! :D Much appreciated. Been trying this for hours.